# AngularJS - How does the DI system know of the name of the arguments?

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, angularjs

Example straight from the official site:

```
function PhoneListCtrl ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('phones/phones.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.phones = data;
    });

    $scope.orderProp = 'age';
}
```

The `$scope` and `$http` arguments are unique identifiers for locating corresponding AngularJS services inside the DI system. So how does the DI system retrieve the variable name of these arguments, exactly?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is the trimmed down version of the way

```
var FN_ARGS = /^function\s*[^\(]*\(\s*([^\)]*)\)/m;
var FN_ARG_SPLIT = /,/;
var FN_ARG = /^\s*(_?)(\S+?)\1\s*$/;
var STRIP_COMMENTS = /((\/\/.*$)|(\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/))/mg;

function annotate(fn){
    var $inject
    if (!($inject = fn.$inject)) {
        $inject = [];
        fnText = fn.toString().replace(STRIP_COMMENTS, '');
        argDecl = fnText.match(FN_ARGS);
        angular.forEach(argDecl[1].split(FN_ARG_SPLIT), function(arg){
            arg.replace(FN_ARG, function(all, underscore, name){
                $inject.push(name);
            });
        });
        fn.$inject = $inject;
    }

    return fn.$inject;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/p6qQT/1/)(See the console);

Steps:
1. Calling `toString` in the function returns the function source
2. Remove all comments using regex
3. Extract the arguments from the source using regex

Answer (score 9):

Straight from the source [@GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/auto/injector.js):

> The simplest form is to extract the dependencies from the arguments of
>   the function. This is done by converting the function into a string
>   using `toString()` method and extracting the argument names.
>
> ```
> // Given
> function MyController($scope, $route) {
>     // ...
> }
> // Then
> expect(injector.annotate(MyController)).toEqual(['$scope', '$route']);
> ```

And the annotate function

```
function annotate(fn) {
  var $inject,
  fnText,
  argDecl,
  last;

  if (typeof fn == 'function') {
    if (!($inject = fn.$inject)) {
      $inject = [];
      fnText = fn.toString().replace(STRIP_COMMENTS, '');
      argDecl = fnText.match(FN_ARGS);
      forEach(argDecl[1].split(FN_ARG_SPLIT), function(arg){
        arg.replace(FN_ARG, function(all, underscore, name){
        $inject.push(name);
      });
    });
    fn.$inject = $inject;
    }
  } else if (isArray(fn)) {
    last = fn.length - 1;
    assertArgFn(fn[last], 'fn')
    $inject = fn.slice(0, last);
  } else {
    assertArgFn(fn, 'fn', true);
  }
  return $inject;
}
```

as seen on row 45 and later