# Get nodejs function definitions

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to gather the source code of defined functions from a js file. The functions can be complex and have many opening and closing brackets so using regex will be hard. I only need functions that are callable later on in the code, like the following

```
function dump_vars() {
    Object.keys(global).forEach(function (key) {
        console.log(key);
        console.log(global[key]);
    });
}
```

Is there a way to get the function definitions from within node.js? Are they maybe saved somewhere like the global object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have access to the function object, then you can get its definition using the `.toString()` method. Per [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString):

> That is, toString decompiles the function, and the string returned includes the function keyword, the argument list, curly braces, and the source of the function body.

For instance, suppose you define a module in `mymodule.js`:

```
function add (a, b) {
    return a + b;
};

function mul (a, b) {
    return a * b;
};

module.exports = {
    a: add,
    b: mul
};
```

Then, in `index.js`:

```
var mymodule = require('./mymodule.js')

Object.keys(mymodule).forEach(function (fun) {
    console.log(mymodule[fun].toString());
})
```

This will output:

```
$ node index.js
function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
function mul(a, b) {
    return a * b;
}
```

*Edit:* For instance, this is how AngularJS implements dependency injection, by using `.toString()` to get back the function code to know the name of the function's arguments. See [this relevant SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15270311/angularjs-how-does-the-di-system-know-of-the-name-of-the-arguments).

Comment: I wont know the function names, the code wont be mine so i would get the function names with regex and then run the toString method on them? Thats a good idea. I will let you know how it turns out :)

Comment: No, what I mean is that you can run `.toString()` on any function object, such as the functions you get when you import a module (which is I think what you want to do when you say *" only need functions that are callable later on in the code"*)

Comment: I cant be certain the rest of the module syntax will be correct.

Comment: Do you want to work on a source file or on the result of a `require()` call? Your question isn't clear.

Comment: Its a source file, i guess, the code doesnt have to run and it might include code that might want to do just that, not only function definitions. Its complicated, your idea of running a toString on every function name though should work, thnx. I will pick your answer as correct.